# macOS Sierra /usr/libexec/lsd crashes during boot, system won't start

Tags: macos

After a installing a system update my Mac mini won't boot at all, or maybe will but only after a few hours of being stuck at boot screen.

I found the following in /var/log/system.log (repeats a lot of timeS):

```
Nov  8 08:30:03 mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[65134]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0]
Nov  8 08:30:03 mac logd[79]: metadata shared cached uuid is null (using logd's shared cache info) lsd (65135)
Nov  8 08:30:03 mac logd[79]: Failed to harvest strings for pathless uuid '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
Nov  8 08:30:03 mac ReportCrash[65063]: Saved crash report for lsd[65134] version 775.8.2 to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/lsd_2016-11-08-083003_mac.crash
Nov  8 08:30:04 mac logd[79]: metadata shared cached uuid is null (using logd's shared cache info) logKextDaemon (65136)
Nov  8 08:30:04 mac logd[79]: Failed to harvest strings for pathless uuid '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
Nov  8 08:30:04 mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.lsd[65135]): Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 sent by exc handler[0]
Nov  8 08:30:05 mac logd[79]: metadata shared cached uuid is null (using logd's shared cache info) lsd (65137)
Nov  8 08:30:05 mac logd[79]: Failed to harvest strings for pathless uuid '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
Nov  8 08:30:05 mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.fsb.logKext[65136]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
Nov  8 08:30:05 mac com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.fsb.logKext): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Nov  8 08:30:05 mac ReportCrash[65063]: Saved crash report for lsd[65135] version 775.8.2 to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/
```

lsd_2016-11-08-083005_mac.crash

Crash report for lsd contains the following stack trace:

```
Thread 12 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.lsd.database
0   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x000000011126ab81 _UTTypeRemove + 76
1   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x0000000111218fe3 _LSBundleRemove + 500
2   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x0000000111241565 _LSServerItemInfoRegistration + 1765
3   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x0000000111243615 ___ZL23_LSDispatchRegistrationP9LSContextPKcPK18LSRegistrationInfoPK8__CFDataS8_PK7__CFURLPK14__CFDictionaryPjPPK9__CFArrayPh_block_invoke + 188
4   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x000000011123c5ab _LSDispatchRegistration(LSContext*, char const*, LSRegistrationInfo const*, __CFData const*, __CFData const*, __CFURL const*, __CFDictionary const*, unsigned int*, __CFArray const**, unsigned char*) + 470
5   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x000000011123b248 _LSRegisterLibrary + 918
6   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x0000000111229f2d _LSRegisterLibraryBundle + 54
7   com.apple.LaunchServices        0x00000001111f0ccb -[LSDatabaseBuilder registerLibraries] + 271
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000112381f5f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000112379128 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000112391413 _dispatch_queue_concurrent_drain + 1423
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000112381d5a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1071
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000112388158 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 369
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011237aee0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000011237acb7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000112732736 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000112732211 start_wqthread + 13
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: A bit of a needle in a haystack - but you could try renaming the "/private/var/db/lsd/" directory to something else and see if it can rebuild the files on next reboot without erroring out.

Comment: @jksoegaard There is no such directory on my system

Comment: Did you find the /private/var/db directory? - i.e. which part of it are you missing exactly?

Comment: @jksoegaard I found `/private/var/db` but there was no `lsd` directory there. I think I'll delete this question as I've already erased the entire disk and now reinstalling the system. Thanks for you help anyway!